# cin.getline() won't separate input according to spaces?

Tags: c++, string, getline

I've been looking for an answer to my question, and couldn't find one.
I'm using:

```
cout << "Enter student's first name and last name:\n";
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
cin.getline(name, 20, ' ');
cin.getline(family, 20, ' ');
```

but the input [such as: David Jones] isn't separated, and is only in 'name'.

Why isn't getline() separating input by it's delimiter? 
Thanks!

full function:

```
    //add a Student to Students.txt
void addStudent(fstream &f1)
{
    //exception
    if (!f1)
        return;
    int id;
    char family[20];
    char name[20];
    bool courses[5];
    cout << "Enter student's ID:\n";
    id = getInteger(id, 1, 100); // id range: (1 <= id <= 100)
    cout << "Enter student's first name and last name:\n";
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cin.getline(name, 20, ' ');
    cin.getline(family, 20, ' ');
    cout << "Enter 0/1 for each of the student's 5 courses\n";
    int boolean; // 0/1 input
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        courses[i] = getInteger(boolean, 0, 1);
    //find out if this id is already taken [=> return]
    if (!f1)
        throw "Error opening -Students.txt- from Project directory.\n";
    if (isInFile("Students.txt", id))
        return;
    /*continue in case the opening was successful AND the id doesn't already exist*/
    Student s(id, family, name, courses);
    //write to our file
    f1.seekp((id - 1) * sizeof(Student)); //(id-1): ids start from 1
    f1.write((char*)&s, sizeof(Student));
}
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/YaI7bo)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you call `cin.ignore(100, '\n')`; I think it's confusing you.

A solution could be, avoiding `ignore()`, simply write

```
cin >> name >> family;
```

but if you want to use `getline()`, I suggest

```
cin.getline(name, 20, ' ');
cin.getline(family, 20, '\n');
```

otherwise you must add a space after the surname.